# Can Kotlin be used with openjdk?

Tags: java, kotlin

I recently discovered Kotlin language, and I wonder if it can be used with openjdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Kotlin does not have a requirement of using the Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to be used since kotlin is a programming language for JVM too